# Find and Group All Records on the Same Month, 1 year apart

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group some records by First Name, Last Name, and Date by Month. Here is my query for grouping by first/last name so far:

```
SELECT `fundraiser_report`.`first_name` AS `first_name`, 
       `fundraiser_report`.`last_name`  AS `last_name`, 
       Count(*)                         AS `count` 
FROM   `fundraiser_report` 
GROUP  BY `fundraiser_report`.`first_name`, 
          `fundraiser_report`.`last_name` 
ORDER  BY `fundraiser_report`.`first_name` ASC, 
          `fundraiser_report`.`last_name` ASC
```

Here is an example of what the data would look like:

```
first_name|last_name|end_date
Hunter    |Cole     |11/37/2019
Hunter    |Cole     |11/20/2018
Hunter    |Cole     |11/13/2020
Andrew    |Barn     |11/37/2019
Andrew    |Barn     |11/20/2018
Andrew    |Barn     |11/13/2020
Anthony   |Jones    |3/11/2010
```

All 7 of these records would need to be returned in a format like this:

```
Hunter |Cole  |3
Andrew |Barn  |3
Anthony|Jones |1
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Nothing is wrong with my query currently, it works as intended. I just cannot figure out how to meet the intent of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: . . Your query would seem to return exactly the results you specify in the question.  That makes it hard for me to understand what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the equivalent of EXTRACT(month FROM sysdate) in mysql
(edited, replaced sysdate with end_date)

```
SELECT fundraiser_report.first_name AS first_name, 
       fundraiser_report.last_name  AS last_name, 
       EXTRACT(month FROM end_date) AS month
       Count(*) AS count 
FROM   fundraiser_report 
GROUP  BY fundraiser_report.first_name, 
          fundraiser_report.last_name,
          EXTRACT(month FROM end_date)
ORDER  BY fundraiser_report.first_name ASC, 
          fundraiser_report.last_name ASC
```

Comment: `EXTRACT(month FROM sysdate)` will be constant. I would use `end_date` instead of `SYSDATE` like OP has in his data